# How to avoid Nested null check

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I want to retrieve the field from API which present inside classes.
Yes I know this is against Law of Demeter but I don't have any option.

Example

```
getClassA().getClassB().getClassC().getClassD().getAccountId();
```

So to add null check as its bad code smell so I come with below code:

```
try{
getClassA().getClassB().getClassC().getClassD().getAccountId();
}catch(NullPointerException ex){
 S.O.P("Null Found");
}
```

or

```
ClassA a = getClassA();
if(a!=null){
ClassB b = a.getClassB();
So on.....
}
```

my question is which is best approach the above mentioned one or explicitly retrieve each class and check null and go to next level
This is against Law of Demeter

Comment: Look here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java8-optional-2175753.html It is exactly explained your problem

Comment: I would say that your architecture/design is not right if you have such problem. As you said yourself, you violate Law of Demeter, which could solve this problem. Could you provide a broader context of what you are trying to do?

Comment: @NwDx Optional won't help here, it would be a set of nested `isPresent()` calls.

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak: Nope, you can call the latest get and only test there.

Comment: Even i agree this is very bad design very tight couple.

This API i am consuming so cant tell them to provide isPresent() or isEmpty() method on Parent .I dont have any other option.

Comment: @NwDx I have checked that before posting here but that is for Java 8 right?I am using Java 7 u 55

Comment: @user2387280 Google's guava provides `Optional` class too

Answer (score 2):

Null Object design pattern is the way to which is being absorbed in Java 8 via Optional class which means you have a wrapper within which either you have the data or you have empty data.

Its something like

```
             MyObject
      RealObject    NullObject
```

Where instead of passing null, you pass NullObject which provides the same interface as MyObject (which can be concrete/abstract/interface class)

Comment: Thanks @SMA for you input i have checked that before posting here but that is for Java8 right?But i am looking for Java 7

Comment: Here I am consuming API so i cant tell them to pass empty nested object.

Comment: Try utilising the same concept as i stated Null Object design pattern. See the class hierarchy that it follows (i just gave a hint above in my answer)

Comment: @user2387280 Your project should be isolated from code that you cannot change. Create your own isolation layer which will expose only the necessary part of third party API you are using. If you are using TDD, this should have integration test.

Comment: Do u see any problem in my option 1?I am handlingexception

Comment: But will you get the accountId and will you e able to perform further operations with out it? Also think about every statement are you going to do such a thing i.e. `try { }catch...`?

Answer (score 2):

This needs Java 8, you are right. I think this will function in a similar way in Guava.

```
public class OptionalTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    A a = new A();
    Optional<A> opa = Optional.ofNullable(a);
    int accid = opa.map(A::getClassB).map(A.B::getClassC).map(A.B.C::getClassD).map(A.B.C.D::getAccountID).orElse(-1);

    if (accid > -1) {
      System.out.println("The account id is: " + accid);
    } else {
      System.out.println("One of them was null. Please play with commenting.");
    }
  }

    static class A {
      B b = new B();
      //B b = null;
      B getClassB() {
        return b;
      }

      static class B {
        //C c = new C();
        C c = null;
        C getClassC() {
          return c;
        }

          static class C {
            D d = new D();
            //D d = null;
            D getClassD() {
              return d;
            }

              static class D {
                private final int accountId = 2;
                int getAccountID() {
                  return accountId;
                }
              }
          }
      }
    }
}
```